# Convert BLOB image to PNG, JPG with Python

Tags: python, blob

I have several blob images in Oracle, so I read them with python.
I can correctly read and convert images from a certain table1 with my code, but when changing to  table2 I cannot execute the same code because I get the following error.

`cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000000000C4520A0>`

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from PIL import Image
#[connection to database with connecting string `conn`]
#[query to acces 1 single image]
result = pd.read_sql(query, conn) #connection to db
img = result["IMAGE"][0].read()  # reading the first BLOB result 
pre_img = io.BytesIO(img)
Image.open(pre_img)
```

This code works well, so the only problem is when I try to read images from table1 . Also at SQL developer I can previsualize the photos from table1, but not with table2. The type of data is BLOB as describe(table) says in Oracle.

value of `img` can be found [here](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2z0s)

[image: sql can't read the image neither]

Comment: The "value of `img`" as posted is a base64-encoded 1-bit Tiff image of a signature. So the data by-itself is a valid image and seems not to be the culprit.

Comment: Can you show in your code example any import statements? Would be useful to know which library you are using for 'Image'. Image is looking for a file path rather than the raw data, maybe the same library has a raw image read function.

Comment: For example the PIL/Pillow function Image.from_bytes might be helpful

Comment: @ypnos Did you use python to see the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
import base64
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img))
```

Comment: How do you know the image is `.png`?

Comment: the image is not `.png` . I am creating an empty file named `imageToSave.png` and then I'm using that empty file to store the BLOB imagen that I am reading from database

Comment: worked fine for me with `with open("imageToSave.jpg", "wb") as fh:`

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "worked fine". Yes, it will save a file, but can you open the file and get back an image? If it's a .png it will fail if you save it as .jpg, and if it's a .jpg it will fail if you save it as .png.

Comment: yes, by "worked fine" I mean that the resulting image could be readed by my viewer. Thanks to your comment I'm aware now that I should not convert any blob input as png image . There is a way to know the original extension of the file?

Comment: If there was a way to know automatically, `Image.open` should have been able to figure it out. You need to know more about how those blobs were written to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Install Pillow module

```
py -m pip install Pillow
```

Use the module to show or save the file from the blob

```
from PIL import Image 

file = request.files['file']
img = Image.open(file.stream)
img.show()
img.save("imagefile.jpg")
```